# Creating SSIS package in SQL Server from Query

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I am new to SQL Server came across SSIS packages. I would like to begin creating a package from a Query but do not know where to start (in terms of starting the package). Can it be built in SSMS or do I need to use other tools such as Data Tools. I have done some research online and many sources refer to BIDS but I don't not think I have that application.

Any tips would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends to some degree on what version of SQL Server you have - after SQL 2012, the SSIS development has been moved to a program called SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools), but prior to that it was BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio).

A [link like this](http://snippetsandhelp.blogspot.com/2013/02/sql-server-installing-bids-2008r2.html) one could help you get the program installed - it assumes you have access to the install disks or program for SQL Server.

As for actually developing the package, there are plenty of tutorials out there to get you started - just Google "SSIS Tutorial" and add the year of your version, and you should find something good.  [MSDN has one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for each version of SQL Server.

Comment: Yes it is 2012. Thank you for you response. And I have it installed. I just cant figure out how to get going. But now that I know I was in the right application I shall keep digging.

Comment: Definitely go through the MSDN link - I've updated it to point at the tutorial for your version.